# Creating an rpm from files and folders from the current directory

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have a GitLab repo with the following structure:

```
clearshare (repo name)
    |---clearshare (yes this is a repeat name)
    |       |---bin
    |       |    |---clearsia
    |       |---app.py
    |       |---base.py
    |       |---cli.py
    |       |---more_files
    |---clearshared.service
    |---clearshare.spec
    |---logging.conf
    |---requirements.txt
    |---setup.py
```

I am trying and failing to set up a spec file for this to build an rpm I can get so far with:

```
Name:      clearshare
Version:   0.0.1 
Release:   1%{?dist}
License:   Proprietary
Summary:   my clearshare program
BuildRoot: %{_builddir}/%{name}
BuildArch: x86_64

Source1: clearshare
Source2: logging.conf
Source3: requirements.txt
Source4: setup.py
Source5: %{name}d.service

Requires: rh-python38

%prep
[ -d %{buildroot} ] && rm -rf %{buildroot}

%install
%define _VENV /var/clearos/envs/%{name}/lib/python3.8/site-packages
mkdir -p -m 755 %{buildroot}%{_VENV}/%{name}
cp -r %{SOURCE1} %{buildroot}%{_VENV}/%{name}
install %{SOURCE2} %{buildroot}%{_VENV}/%{name}/logging.conf
install %{SOURCE3} %{buildroot}%{_VENV}/%{name}/requirements.txt
install %{SOURCE4} %{buildroot}%{_VENV}/%{name}/setup.py
install -D %{SOURCE5} %{buildroot}/usr/lib/systemd/system/%{name}d.service
# Exit install without trying to compile the python code
exit 0

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{_VENV}/%{name}/%{name}
%{_VENV}/%{name}/logging.conf
%{_VENV}/%{name}/requirements.txt
%{_VENV}/%{name}/setup.py
%{_unitdir}/%{name}d.service
```

There is a bit more to it but I don't think it matters for the moment. I can build the rpm locally without any of the Sources specified but src.rpm fails with an empty set of files to package. If I specify Source1-5 I get a src.rpm with files Source2-5 in it and folder Source1, but the folder Source1 is empty. How to I get the src.rpm to recursively pack all the files and folders under the clearshare subfolder without naming them individually? If it helps, everything under clearshare/ is pyhon except the bin folder which is a binary.

There are some restrictions because the build system I end up using cannot fetch files during the build phase so uses a sources.download file with the link and sha265sum. When creating the sources.download I don't know the sha256sum as it will change when once I know it and put it in the file so I need to avoid this.

How can I pull in the subfolder contents into the src.rpm without specifying all the lower level files? I don't mind if I just have to individually the specify clearshare/bin/clearsia file.

Comment: The `sources.download` and the SHA are not part of the code you provided, so it's difficult to understand how they are used and thus try to help on this point.

Comment: The sources.download would contain something like:
`9d5adf74e8b439cff0ee26fe4619dcf30588665a13d4208b85a7dc6d62989782 clearshare.tar.gz https://gitlab.com/clearos/clearfoundation/clearshare/-/archive/9c9925aa3d6723dcc264abae81055b6e9f4059a5/clearshare-9c9925aa3d6723dcc264abae81055b6e9f4059a5.tar.gz`  

But using that would put me in a chicken and egg situation. It can only really be used if I create another package to build this one. I may have to go down that route.

Answer (score 3):

The easier (and standard) way is packaging the folder `clearshare` as a `tar.gz` archive:

```
mv clearshare clearshare-0.0.1
tar -cvzf clearshare-0.0.1.tar.gz clearshare-0.0.1/
mv clearshare-0.0.1.tar.gz ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
cp clearshare/clearshare.spec ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
```

and then load the tarball directly in the `.specfile`:

```
Name:    clearshare
Version: 0.0.1
Release: 1%{?dist}
License: Proprietary
Summary: my clearshare program
Source0: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

Requires: rh-python38

BuildArch: x86_64

%description
Clearshare proprietary package.

%prep
%setup -q

%install
install clearshare/[...] %{buildroot}...
install -D -m 644 %{name}d.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/%{name}d.service

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
...
%{_unitdir}/%{name}d.service
```

Any file required only in the build process (`clearshare.spec`, `requirements.txt`, `setup.py`) should not be packaged in the binary rpm . The build process should be coded in the `%build` section.

If the sources are located in a git repository you can do a git clone instead of using a `Source0` tarball.

Comment: I am not used to stackoverflow, so I added an answer but it has appeared above yours which was not the intention.
I also need to add that setup.py is needed to be packaged as it is then used to install into a virtual environment

Comment: The build of your application should be done by the `rpmbuild`. It's very unusual to package a virtual environment in an rpm for building the software in another way. Why not just do a git clone (assuming you use git as control system) in the target build environment?

Comment: .... which points to using a new package with the spec file pointing to this one, I think.

Comment: Hmmm. The specfile is already provided by the `.src.rpm`.

Comment: I added the spec file but I can't get it to work. This repo really belongs to another developer who has created the python virtual environment but he has even less of an idea about rpm packaging than me.
I have now backed out the spec file and created another package, clearlifed which contains just a spec file, a sources.download and the clearlifed.service file. This pulls a tar.gz correctly and builds correctly in mock. I had been hoping to avoid the extra package but I don't know how to do it :(